# In how long would an SSD pay for itself in energy savings?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

UPDATE:

- Both my current HDD and the SSD I would buy are 4TB (as seen in the 2 hard drive links I provided)
- My current electric rate is $0.149 / kWh
- How much electricity the Aktio enclosure consumes does not matter because the only thing that would change is the actual hard drive.

=========================

I currently run a Western Digital WD4005FZBX https://shrtm.nu/9xFv for about 10 hours per day. This drive is inside an Akitio external enclosure https://shrtm.nu/9xFv

If I switch over to an SSD the likes of https://shrtm.nu/sTqy how long will it take to pay for itself in electricity bill savings (assuming I simply swap the drives and keep my setup as-is)?

I'm not sure how to calculate this to figure it out.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: That's almost impossible to work out as the WD4005FZBX  has different power consumptions for  R/W, idle, and standby. It also varies depending on the disk size (which you don't specify). Same for the SSD.

Comment: It also depends on how much you pay for your electric, which you also don't specify.

Comment: It also makes an assumption that the power requirements of the enclosure would change based on the drive contained within it.  I would have to study the specifications for both drives to make that decision.

Comment: @Projectguru - please also avoid using shortened links here, there is no good reason to do this and it can make people wary of clicking / helping.